# Skip Build of Tycho Module

Tags: tycho

I want to skip the build of a couple tycho modules for a specific profile, but evidently the Maven way does not work.

I tried `mvn install -pl "!org.acme.project"` but got:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: org.acme.project @ 
[ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: org.acme.project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MavenExecutionException
```

(Which makes sense, because Tycho artifacts are never known as Maven artifacts, so of course Maven does not find them.)

And I tried overridding the modules like this:

```
<modules>
    <module>org.acme.project</module>
    <module>org.acme.other</module>
</modules>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>my-great-profile</id>

        <modules>
            <module>org.acme.other</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

But all projects are built that way (I'm not sure if that *should* work, or if I can only add modules that way).

Creating a default profile does not work, because then Eclipse won't let me import these projects.

I could probably disable all used Maven / Tycho plug-ins manually, but that's tedious.

Is there an easy way to skip Tycho modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Which makes sense, because Tycho artifacts are never known as Maven artifacts, so of course Maven does not find them.)

That is not completely correct; Tycho projects are part of the Maven reactor, upon which `-pl` acts. Point in favor: `mvn install -pl ":org.acme.project"` does work.

But note the colon in the above command (which AFAICT means “the project with `org.acme.project` *artifact* ID and **any** *group* ID“). Thus, the following should do the trick for you:

```
mvn install -pl "!:org.acme.project"
```